# Error when i try to make relationships in adonis, how i can determine the columns that will return in each relationship? is returning only the id

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

Actually i have this query:

```
async show({ request }){
    const { page, pageSize } = request.get();
    const book = await Book.find(request.params.id)
    const questions = await book
    .book_unit_questions()
    .paginate(page, pageSize)
    return questions
}
```

This return something like:

```
{id: 15, book_unit_id: 4, question_form: "Som", option_form: "Texto", type_answer: "Aberta",…}
```

In this json i need the description of the book_unit_id.

I try:

```
async show({ request }){
    const { page, pageSize } = request.get();
    const book = await Book.find(request.params.id)
    const questions = await book
    .book_unit()
    .book_unit_questions()
    .paginate(page, pageSize)
    return questions
}
```

But this way i get:

> error: {message: "book.book_unit(...).book_unit_questions is not a
>   function", name: "TypeError", status: 500,…}

This is my Book model:

```
class Book extends Model {

    user () {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/User')
            .select('id', 'username')
    }

    book_unit(){
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/BookUnit')
            .select('id', 'description as unit')

    }

    book_unit_questions() {
        return this.manyThrough('App/Models/BookUnit', 'book_unit_questions')
    }

}
```

This is my bookUnit model:

```
class BookUnit extends Model {

    static get table () {
        return 'book_unit'
    }

    book_unit_questions() {
        return this.hasMany('App/Models/BookUnitQuestion')
    }

    book () {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/Book')
        .select('id', 'description as descricaounidade')
    }


    user () {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/User')
            .select('id', 'username')
    }

}
```

and this is my bookunitquestion:

```
class BookUnitQuestion extends Model {

    static get table () {
        return 'book_unit_question'
    }

    user () {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/User')
            .select('id', 'username')
    }

    books () {
        return this.manyThrough('App/Models/Book', 'book_units')
    }  

}
```

How i can add to return questions the description column value of the book_unit and the username column value of the user_id?

Answer (score 1):

- The relationship between the Book model & Book_Unit model is
  `hasMany`.
- The `select` on the method `book_unit` on `Book` model should contain `book_id`.
  Otherwise, books cannot be mapped.

Here are the updated models.

`Book` Model

```
class Book extends Model {

  book_unit() {
    return this.hasMany("App/Models/BookUnit").select(
      "id",
      "book_id", // added book_id, rename this with the actual Foreign key
      "description as unit"
    );
  }

  book_unit_questions() {
    return this.manyThrough("App/Models/BookUnit", "book_unit_questions");
  }
}
```

Fetch Books with relationships.

```
const questions = await Book.query()
  .where({ id: request.params.id })
  .with("book_unit_questions") // Load as many relationships
  .paginate(page, pageSize);
```

Comment: This way i have several problems:

1- The paginate is applying in book, not in the book_unit_questions. I only search for only one book, so, the paginate never works

2- for each book_unit_question i need to know what is your book_unit.description and book_unit.unit